# Number format on sliderInput tick mark labels

Tags: shiny

I am deploying a shiny app with German text and number formats on a machine with en en_US locale.
Using `format` I can format all my outputs according to German rules for numbers (decimal comma instead of decimal point, ...).

But I have not found a way to change the number format on a slider to German. The docs say that the `locale` parameter os sliderInput is deprecated.
Is there another way of getting the number format I need?

Answer (score 1):

The message from `shiny` is:

> The `locale` argument to sliderInput is deprecated. Use `sep`, `pre`, and `post` instead.

So setting `sep = "."`:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("foo", "bar", min = 1E4, max = 5E4, step = 1E4, value = 2E4, sep = ".")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```